# rows_manipulation of pandas with date_time with datatime from 0-30 hours

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```
import pandas as pd
d= {'start_time': ["06:30:00", "07:30:00", "24:30:00","17:30:00","22:30:00","16:30:00"], 'final_time': ["09:30:00", "23:30:00", "27:30:00","26:30:00","23:30:00","23:00:00"], 'time_squence': [22, 33, 223,333,3321,76]}
data=pd.DataFrame(d)
```

so in this pandas i want remove the rows
that either in start_time or final_time that has a time more than 24hours and then update the pandas. as python cannot convert those strings(times) to datetime object.

```
d= {'start_time': ["06:30:00", "07:30:00","22:30:00","16:30:00"], 'final_time': ["09:30:00", "23:30:00","23:30:00","23:00:00"], 'time_squence': [22, 33,3321,76]}
data=pd.DataFrame(d)
```

thats the expected output and values should be converted to datetime object

Comment: Can you add expected ouput after update the pandas?

Comment: d= {'start_time': ["06:30:00", "07:30:00","22:30:00","16:30:00"], 'final_time': ["09:30:00", "23:30:00","23:30:00","23:00:00"], 'time_squence': [22, 33,3321,76]}                                               then data=pd.DataFrame(d)

Comment: and the values should be also converted to datetime object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter first 2 values if less like `24` hours first in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with convert values to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and compare seconds by [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```
d= {'start_time': ["24:00:00", "07:30:00", "24:30:00","17:30:00","22:30:00","16:30:00"], 
    'final_time': ["09:30:00", "23:30:00", "27:30:00","26:30:00","23:30:00","23:00:00"], 
    'time_squence': [22, 33, 223,333,3321,76]}
data=pd.DataFrame(d)

day_sec = 86400
m1 = pd.to_timedelta(data['start_time']).dt.total_seconds() <= day_sec
m2 = pd.to_timedelta(data['final_time']).dt.total_seconds() <= day_sec

data = data[m1 & m2].copy()
print (data)
  start_time final_time  time_squence
0   24:00:00   09:30:00            22
1   07:30:00   23:30:00            33
4   22:30:00   23:30:00          3321
5   16:30:00   23:00:00            76
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. if the OP dont whant `.apply()`

Comment: @The.B - Ya, maybe some reason why using your code, it is still for OP what use ;) Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `.dropna()`, first you can use `.apply()` so we get the hours.
code below:

```
data["final"] = data["final_time"].apply(lambda x:x if int(x[0:2]) >= 24  and int(x[3:5]) > 0 else False )
data["start"] = data["start_time"].apply(lambda x:x if int(x[0:2]) >= 24 and int(x[3:5]) > 0  else False )
data["final"] = data[data["final"] == False]
data["start"] = data[data["start"] == False]
data.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True)
data = data.iloc[:,:-2]
data
data
```

output:

```
    start_time  final_time  time_squence
0   06:30:00    09:30:00    22
1   07:30:00    23:30:00    33
4   22:30:00    23:30:00    3321
5   16:30:00    23:00:00    76
```

Comment: i was wondering can u add this to this lambda x:x if int(x[0:2]) >= 24 and int(x[2:5])>0 else False , so if there is a time that is 24:00:00 it wont be removed and if there is time that is 24:01:00 it would be removed

Comment: you mean that you whant to remove everythin above hour=24? so 24:01 will be removed? wait let me edit my code

Comment: yes but i want to save values with 24:00:00 as well

Comment: you are slicing wrong, the if statement should look like this and if `int(x[0:2]) >= 24 and int(x[3:5]) > 0`

Comment: so it should be data["final"] = data["final_time"].apply(lambda x:x if int(x[0:2]) >= 24 and int(x[3:5]) > 0 else False )?

Comment: not quite, the if must check be diffrent.

Comment: so how can i fix this?

Comment: @AliMozard - Better is avoid apply, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54432583/2901002)

Comment: both yes and no, if your data is big, dont use it. else, it will do the work for you.

Comment: @The.B - added vectorized not apply solution.